# Non CRUD Route in FeathersJS

Tags: javascript, feathersjs, feathers-sequelize, feathers-hook, feathers-service

I have a service `results` that handles all CRUD Operations for the `results` service in `feathersjs`. How would I create a route `/results/:id/hr_bar_graph` which basically fetches the result at that particular id and uses the resulting data to create an bar graph.

My code currently is:

```
module.exports = function (app) {


const Model = createModel(app);
  const paginate = app.get('paginate');

  const options = {
    name: 'results',
    Model,
    paginate
  };



// Initialize our service with any options it requires
  app.use('/results', createService(options));

  app.use('/results/:id/hr_bargraph_image', {
    find(id, params){
      this.app.service('results').get(id)
        .then(function(response){
          console.log(response);
        })
        .cathc(function(error){
          console.log(error);
        })
      return Promise.resolve({
        imageData: ''
      });
    }
  });

  // Get our initialized service so that we can register hooks and filters
  const service = app.service('results');

  service.hooks(hooks);
};
```

Been stuck here for a while now. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference, from [this issue](https://github.com/feathersjs/docs/issues/1136), the answer is to use [params.route](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/express.html#paramsroute) and Feathers normal [find(params)](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html#findparams):

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  const Model = createModel(app);
  const paginate = app.get('paginate');

  const options = {
    name: 'results',
    Model,
    paginate
  };

  // Initialize our service with any options it requires
  app.use('/results', createService(options));

  app.use('/results/:id/hr_bargraph_image', {
    async find(params){
      const { id } = params.route;
      const results = await app.service('results').get(id);

      return {
        imageData: ''
      };
    }
  });

  // Get our initialized service so that we can register hooks and filters
  const service = app.service('results');

  service.hooks(hooks);
};
```

Comment: How do I apply the same hooks I have on the results service to this custom service? Without affecting the working of the `results` service